# How to make button not holdable pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a button function in PyGame, and here is the code for that:

```
def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action = None):
    global mousedown
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, COLORS[ic], (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action is not None:
            mousedown = True
            function = action()
            return function
```

The problem I am having is if I hold the button down, the function passed to the button is repeated until the mouse unclicks. Is there a way to fix it so the user can only press the button once, and has to release and repress to repeat the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a `not_press` condition at the beginning of the function which get's set to `false` at the end of the `button()` call and get's set back to true when `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP` is registered (i.e when the button is unclicked).

Something like:

```
def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action = None):
    if not_press == True
        global mousedown
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, COLORS[ic], (x, y, w, h))
            if click[0] == 1 and action is not None:
                mousedown = True
                function = action()
                not_press = False #note this will only disable the button() if the code get's that far ... if you want to disable it no matter what just change the indent (see grayed comment below)
                return function
     #not_press = False # if put here will only allow the user to press the button once no matter if the content can be done or not
```

and then, in your main event loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        quit()
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP: #This will check if you have unclicked
        not_press = True # and only then reset the condition for the content of Button() to be done again
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a button function , you can use the built in function of the pygame module.

This is the main function of module to check the mouse clicks.

> pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: #This will check if you clicked the mouse
            if event.button == 1:  # left mouse button? #Checks if you did left click 

            #Do rest....
```

Comment: Wouldn't that still repeat the command at each game loop if the button remains pressed ?

Comment: What you said is 
"Is there a way to fix it so the user can only press the button once, and has to release and repress to repeat the function?"
So yes , if you release the button , you have to click it again in order to get the function.